# SQL update fields of one table from fields of another one

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I have two tables:

```
A [ID, column1, column2, column3]
B [ID, column1, column2, column3, column4]
```

`A` will always be subset of `B` (meaning all columns of `A` are also in `B`).

I want to update a record with a specific `ID` in `B` with their data from `A` for all columns of `A`. This `ID` exists both in `A` and `B`.

Is there an `UPDATE` syntax or any other way to do that without specifying the column names, just saying *"set all columns of A"*?

I'm using PostgreSQL, so a specific non-standard command is also accepted (however, not preferred).

Comment: I think this is what you wanna do,
https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/58383

Answer (score 386):

You can use the non-standard [FROM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-update.html) clause.

```
UPDATE table_to_be_updated b
SET column1 = a.column1,
    column2 = a.column2,
    column3 = a.column3
FROM lookup_table a
WHERE a.id = b.id
AND b.id = 1
```

Comment: The question is asking about how to do it *without* specifying all the column names.  (And I am too.)

Comment: I agree with @cluesque, but this answer is an excellent way to use values in one column in a table as a lookup table for replacing values in a column in another table (see [SO 21657475](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657475/update-one-field-from-another-table/50239731#50239731)), so +1 ...

Comment: Why b.id = 1 is needed ?

Comment: @YasirAzgar the b.id = 1 is to limit what rows in b get updated.  Otherwise we would update every row in the table.  Occasionally, that might be what you want. But the original question was to update a specific row in b.

Comment: This is what I needed for my particular problem: updating one table's column with values from another table's differently-named column.

Comment: can i use alias for tables ?

Comment: Non-standard, do you mean that this would not work with Oracle?

Comment: Great answer! Just this caveat: don't try to use the alias (b) in the set like: SET b.column1 = ... . Column1 MUST be of table_to_be_updated, so using the alias would raise an error

Answer (score 65):

<sub>The question is old but I felt the best answer hadn't been given, yet.</sub>

> Is there an `UPDATE` syntax ... **without specifying the column names**?

### General solution with dynamic SQL

#### Knowing only the primary key column of both tables

You don't need to know any column names except for some unique column(s) to join on (**`id`** in the example). Works reliably for any possible corner case I can think of.

This is specific to PostgreSQL. I am building dynamic code based on the the [information_schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html), in particular the table [`information_schema.columns`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html), which is defined in the SQL standard and most major RDBMS (except Oracle) have it. But a [`DO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) statement with [PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) code executing dynamic SQL is totally non-standard PostgreSQL syntax.

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN

EXECUTE (
SELECT
  'UPDATE b
   SET   (' || string_agg(        quote_ident(column_name), ',') || ')
       = (' || string_agg('a.' || quote_ident(column_name), ',') || ')
   FROM   a
   WHERE  b.id = 123
   AND    a.id = b.id'
FROM   information_schema.columns
WHERE  table_name   = 'a'       -- table name, case sensitive
AND    table_schema = 'public'  -- schema name, case sensitive
AND    column_name <> 'id'      -- all columns except id
);

END
$do$;
```

Assuming a matching column in `b` for *every* column in `a`, but not the other way round. `b` can have additional columns.

`WHERE  b.id = 123` is optional, to update a selected row.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cf344090ee37d818ca2356678d0451c8)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cdd2b/3)</sub>

Related answers with more explanation:

- [Dynamic UPDATE fails due to unwanted parenthesis around string in plpgsql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/65229/3684)
- [Update multiple columns that start with a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344161/update-multiple-columns-that-start-with-a-specific-string/16349111#16349111)

### Partial solutions with plain SQL

#### Knowing the list of shared columns

You know the list of column names that both tables share. With a syntax shortcut for updating multiple columns - shorter than what other answers suggested so far in any case.

```sql
UPDATE b
SET   (  column1,   column2,   column3)
    = (a.column1, a.column2, a.column3)
FROM   a
WHERE  b.id = 123    -- optional, to update only selected row
AND    a.id = b.id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cf344090ee37d818ca2356678d0451c8)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cdd2b/3)</sub>

This syntax was introduced with Postgres 8.2 in 2006, long before the question was asked. [Details in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html)

Related:

- [Bulk update of all columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/63883/3684)

#### Knowing list of columns in `B`

If all columns of `A` are defined `NOT NULL` (but not necessarily all columns of `B`),
*and* you know the column names of `B` (but not necessarily those of `A`).

```sql
UPDATE b
SET   (column1, column2, column3, column4)
    = (COALESCE(ab.column1, b.column1)
     , COALESCE(ab.column2, b.column2)
     , COALESCE(ab.column3, b.column3)
     , COALESCE(ab.column4, b.column4)
      )
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM   a
   NATURAL LEFT JOIN  b -- append missing columns
   WHERE  b.id IS NULL  -- only if anything actually changes
   AND    a.id = 123    -- optional, to update only selected row
   ) ab
WHERE b.id = ab.id;
```

The [`NATURAL LEFT JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) joins a row from `b` where all columns of the same name hold same values. We don't need an update in this case (nothing changes) and can eliminate those rows early in the process (`WHERE  b.id IS NULL`).
We still need to find a matching row, so `b.id = ab.id` in the outer query.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b83402a239fb441acac05d22de143797)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/62fce/1)</sub>

This is standard SQL [except for the `FROM` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html#id-1.9.3.182.10).
It works no matter which of the columns are actually present in `A`, but the query cannot distinguish between actual NULL values and missing columns in `A`, so it is only reliable if all columns in `A` are defined `NOT NULL`.

There are multiple possible variations, depending on what you *know* about both tables.

Comment: The power of SQL! Just noticed when you add parenthesis in the set clause (`SET   (column1) = (a.column)`) Postgres will treat it as a another kind of update and give and error like this:
`source for a multiple-column UPDATE item must be a sub-SELECT or ROW() expression`

Answer (score 37):

I have been working with IBM DB2 database for more then decade and now trying to learn PostgreSQL.

**It works on PostgreSQL 9.3.4, but does not work on DB2 10.5:**

```
UPDATE B SET
     COLUMN1 = A.COLUMN1,
     COLUMN2 = A.COLUMN2,
     COLUMN3 = A.COLUMN3
FROM A
WHERE A.ID = B.ID
```

Note: Main problem is FROM cause that is not supported in DB2 and also not in ANSI SQL.

**It works on DB2 10.5, but does NOT work on PostgreSQL 9.3.4:**

```
UPDATE B SET
    (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) =
               (SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3 FROM A WHERE ID = B.ID)
```

**FINALLY! It works on both PostgreSQL 9.3.4 and DB2 10.5:**

```
UPDATE B SET
     COLUMN1 = (SELECT COLUMN1 FROM A WHERE ID = B.ID),
     COLUMN2 = (SELECT COLUMN2 FROM A WHERE ID = B.ID),
     COLUMN3 = (SELECT COLUMN3 FROM A WHERE ID = B.ID)
```

Comment: Note that the second and third queries are not completely equivalent to the the first. If no matching row is found in `B`, the first statement does *nothing* (original row remains untouched), while the other two overwrite columns with NULL values.

Answer (score 9):

This is a great help. The code

```
UPDATE tbl_b b
SET   (  column1,   column2,   column3)
    = (a.column1, a.column2, a.column3)
FROM   tbl_a a
WHERE  b.id = 1
AND    a.id = b.id;
```

works perfectly.

noted that you need a bracket "" in

```
From "tbl_a" a
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

Not necessarily what you asked, but maybe using postgres inheritance might help?

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    ID            int,
    column1       text,
    column2       text,
    column3       text
);

CREATE TABLE B (
    column4       text
) INHERITS (A);
```

This avoids the need to update B.

But be sure to read all the [details](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/ddl-inherit.html).

Otherwise, what you ask for is not considered a good practice - dynamic stuff such as views with `SELECT * ...` are discouraged (as such slight convenience might break more things than help things), and what you ask for would be equivalent for the `UPDATE ... SET` command.

Comment: I not sure how inheritance will solve this. Do you mean adding an update trigger for A that also updates B?
I don't want to synchronize A with B all the time, only upon request. And in such case, I can't use the triggers.

Comment: Yes, if it is only in certain cases then inheritance would not work and in that case I advise against dynamic query approach.
(still there are ways to achieve this using postgres procedural languages. also if you want to use triggers you can use them as well - by adding sync field for example firing trigger only when it is set).

Answer (score 0):

you can build and execute dynamic sql to do this, but its really not ideal

Comment: I thought about that. I thought I could make my query compliant with later changes to both tables, but dynamic sql seems to be too complicated than just specify all fields and forget about forward compatibility.

Comment: yes, it will be complicated, but should be forward compatible with later columns being added or removed. You'll have to first do a query to get the column names from both tables, then match the column names and then write the dynamic sql to do the update based on the matching column names. a fun project actually :)

Answer (score -5):

Try Following

```
Update A a, B b, SET a.column1=b.column1 where b.id=1
```

EDITED:- Update more than one column

```
Update A a, B b, SET a.column1=b.column1, a.column2=b.column2 where b.id=1
```

Comment: I don't understand how it copies column1, column2 and column3. And I do need to explicit mention column1.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get the following error: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","

Comment: This non-standard syntax would work for [`UPDATE` in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html), but it's invalid for PostgreSQL.