# Update multiple columns that start with a specific string

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to update a bunch of columns in a DB for testing purposes of a feature. I have a table that is built with hibernate so all of the columns that are created for an embedded entity begin with the same name. I.e. `contact_info_address_street1`, `contact_info_address_street2`, etc.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to do something to the affect of:

```
UPDATE table SET contact_info_address_* = null;
```

If not, I know I can do it the long way, just looking for a way to help myself out in the future if I need to do this all over again for a different set of columns.

Comment: You'll need to read metadata. Check tables `pg_%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no handy shortcut sorry. If you have to do this kind of thing a lot, you could create a function to dynamically execute sql and achieve your goal.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION reset_cols() RETURNS boolean AS $$ BEGIN 
    EXECUTE (select 'UPDATE table SET ' 
                  || array_to_string(array(
                              select column_name::text 
                              from information_schema.columns 
                              where table_name = 'table' 
                              and column_name::text like 'contact_info_address_%'
                     ),' = NULL,') 
                  || ' = NULL'); 
    RETURN true; 
 END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- run the function
SELECT reset_cols();
```

It's not very nice though. A better function would be one that accepts the tablename and column prefix as args. Which I'll leave as an exercise for the readers :)

Comment: I like the answer, if nothing better comes along i will mark it as accepted.  (thanks for the info =)  )

Comment: Careful, column names need to be escaped. This allows SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

You need dynamic SQL for this. So you must defend against possible SQL injection.

#### Basic query

The basic query to generate the DML command needed can look like this:

```sql
SELECT format('UPDATE tbl SET (%s) = (%s)'
               ,string_agg (quote_ident(attname), ', ')
               ,string_agg ('NULL', ', ')
             )
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
AND    NOT attisdropped 
AND    attnum > 0
AND    attname ~~ 'foo_%';
```

Returns:

```
UPDATE tbl SET (foo_a, foo_b, foo_c) = (NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Make use of the ["**column-list syntax**" of `UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) to shorten the code and simplify the task.

I query the [**system catalogs**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) instead of [information schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) because the latter, while being standardized and guaranteed to be portable across major versions, is also notoriously slow and sometimes unwieldy. There are pros and cons, see:

- [Get column names and data types of a query, table or view](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75124/3684)

`quote_ident()` for the column names prevents SQL-injection - also necessary for identifiers.

[`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) requires 9.0+.

#### Full automation with PL/pgSQL function

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_update_cols(_tbl regclass, _col_pattern text
                                       , OUT row_ct int, OUT col_ct bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO _sql, col_ct
          format('UPDATE tbl SET (%s) = (%s)'
               , string_agg (quote_ident(attname), ', ')
               , string_agg ('NULL', ', ')
                )
        , count(*)
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
   AND    NOT attisdropped            -- no dropped columns
   AND    attnum > 0                  -- no system columns
   AND    attname LIKE _col_pattern;  -- only columns matching pattern

   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;         -- output SQL for debugging
   EXECUTE _sql;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;
END
$func$;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_update_cols(regclass, text)
IS 'Updates all columns of table _tbl ($1)
that match _col_pattern ($2) in a LIKE expression.
Returns the count of columns (col_ct) and rows (row_ct) affected.';
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_update_cols('myschema.tbl', 'foo%');
```

To make the function more practical, it returns information as described in the comment. More about [obtaining the result status](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS) in plpgsql in the manual.

I use the variable `_sql` to hold the query string, so I can collect the number of columns found (`col_ct`) in the same query.

The object identifier type `regclass` is the most efficient way to automatically avoid SQL injection (and sanitize non-standard names) for the table name, too. You can use **schema-qualified table names** to avoid ambiguities. I would advise to do so if you (can) have multiple schemas in your db! See:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=504ec4f80345f8d94cbd99f1087c0d2c)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/03558/1)</sub>