# Use an eval function to return table

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am interested in learning how to use dynamic functions in Postgres. I basically need a dynamic function that will spit out a table or a subtable (a few chosen columns from an existing table).

I've created the following `eval()` function, but it is not working as I'd like it to. 
I would like my function to return the result of a query that is introduced as a string within the function. The function currently returns only the first value from the first column (`enrich_d_dkj_p_k27ac`). It seems like I should change my `returns` from `text` to something else?

```
create or replace function eval() returns text
as
$body$
declare
  result text;
begin
  execute 'select enrich_d_dkj_p_k27ac,enrich_lr_dkj_p_k27ac,enrich_r_dkj_p_k27ac
  from dkj_p_k27ac' into result;
  return result;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;

SELECT eval();
```

Result is:

```
eval text
2.4
```

But this is basically only the very first value of the first column - I will need the entire table to appear - or in other words - the result of the indicated `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *would* work like this (but it's useless):

```
create or replace function eval()
  RETURNS TABLE (enrich_d_dkj_p_k27ac text  -- replace with actual column types
               , enrich_lr_dkj_p_k27ac text
               , enrich_r_dkj_p_k27ac text) AS
$func$
begin

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
'select enrich_d_dkj_p_k27ac,enrich_lr_dkj_p_k27ac,enrich_r_dkj_p_k27ac
 from dkj_p_k27ac';

end
$func$  language plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM eval();
```

You do not need the `eval()` function, just execute the statement directly:

```
select enrich_d_dkj_p_k27ac,enrich_lr_dkj_p_k27ac,enrich_r_dkj_p_k27ac
from dkj_p_k27ac;
```

The dynamic call cannot solve your underlying problem:

- [How to execute a string result of a stored procedure in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808534/how-to-execute-a-string-result-of-a-stored-procedure-in-postgres/27812097#27812097)