# How to ON CONFLICT update NULL columns in the original table using Postgres without listing every column?

Tags: postgresql

I am reading through a large list of data and adding it to a PostgreSQL database. The problem is, sometimes there are duplicate values in the data I'm reading in, but sometimes they fill in data that was missing previously. To remedy this, I have added the following to my script, but it is very ugly:

```
INSERT INTO tab(id,col1,col2,col3,...) VALUES (i,v1,v2,v3,...)
ON CONFLICT (id)
    DO UPDATE 
        SET 
            (col1,col2,col3, ...)=(
                COALESCE(tab.col1, EXCLUDED.col1),
                COALESCE(tab.col2, EXCLUDED.col2),
                COALESCE(tab.col3, EXCLUDED.col3),
                ...
             );
```

I'm hoping there's a more elegant solution than manually writing out every column in the table. I have a few more tables I need to write these for so I'd prefer if there was a more generic way to do this.

EDIT: I'm pretty new to this, and reading the docs, this may be a dumb way to do this in the first place. Please let me know if I should even be using the `INSERT` command for this, it looks like maybe just `UPDATE` or some form of `JOIN` could accomplish the same thing?

Postgres version:
`psql (PostgreSQL) 12.14 (Ubuntu 12.14-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)`

Comment: No, spelling out the columns that you want to insert/update is a good practice and is the way to go.

Comment: You lead with *"I am reading through a large list of data"*. But then you show a single-row UPSERT. Shouldn't that be a multi-row command (with many input rows?). Can you consolidate the whole operation into a single command? (Then I would suggest a very much different approach, cheaper approach. Please always declare your version of Postgres.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I have edited the OP to show the version, 12.14. 
And possibly. But often I have to add to different tables, the data is all mixed together in the bigger file I'm parsing. But if it's faster to read through the file |Tables| times and do a single insert for each, I'd be interested in the other approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's necessary to list every column, but it's not necessary to enter the list manually. The following query is an example of using column information found in information_schema to generate the SET clause:

```
WITH query_fragments AS (
    SELECT
        string_agg(quote_ident(c.column_name), ', ' ORDER BY c.ordinal_position) AS column_list,
        string_agg(format('COALESCE(tab.%I, excluded.%I)', c.column_name, c.column_name), ', ' ORDER BY c.ordinal_position) AS column_values
    FROM
        information_schema.columns c
    WHERE
        c.table_schema = 'public'
        AND c.table_name = 'tab'
        AND c.column_name <> 'id'
)
SELECT
    format('SET (%s) = (%s)', column_list, column_values) AS set_clause
FROM
    query_fragments;
```

This could easily be incorporated into a function and expanded to generate the entire insert query for each table.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks mostly good. As does [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20151367/johnh)'s meta-query to build it.

One major issue remains: don't update rows that don't actually change. That accrues the full update cost for no gain.

```
INSERT INTO tab AS t
       (id, col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (i , v1  , v2  , v3  )
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET   (col1, col2, col3) =
      (COALESCE(t.col1, EXCLUDED.col1),
       COALESCE(t.col2, EXCLUDED.col2),
       COALESCE(t.col3, EXCLUDED.col3))
WHERE  EXCLUDED IS DISTINCT FROM t;
```

**Better** (but more verbose):

```sql
...
WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IS DISTINCT FROM 
      (COALESCE(t.col1, EXCLUDED.col1),
       COALESCE(t.col2, EXCLUDED.col2),
       COALESCE(t.col3, EXCLUDED.col3));     -- !!!
```

The first suggestion only suppresses updates where the input row is exactly the same as the existing row.
The second (**better**) suggestion suppresses all empty updates.

Related:

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)
- [Mass-Coalescing of Null Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306683/mass-coalescing-of-null-values/33312794#33312794)
- [Update multiple columns in a trigger function in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343075/update-multiple-columns-in-a-trigger-function-in-plpgsql/15351196#15351196)
- [Update multiple columns that start with a specific string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344161/update-multiple-columns-that-start-with-a-specific-string/16349111#16349111)

#### Superior approach

My above suggestions help to minimize the number of expensive updates.
If you can manage without adding too much overhead, don't update the same row repeatedly at all. **Consolidate multiple input rows into a single row** before applying the `UPDATE`.

Like:

```
INSERT INTO tab AS t
      (id, col1   , col2   , col3)
SELECT i , min(v1), min(v2), min(v3)
FROM   my_input_rows i
GROUP  BY 1
ON     CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
SET   (col1, col2, col3) =
      (COALESCE(t.col1, EXCLUDED.col1),
       COALESCE(t.col2, EXCLUDED.col2),
       COALESCE(t.col3, EXCLUDED.col3))
WHERE (col1, col2, col3) IS DISTINCT FROM 
      (COALESCE(t.col1, EXCLUDED.col1),
       COALESCE(t.col2, EXCLUDED.col2),
       COALESCE(t.col3, EXCLUDED.col3));
```

You might first write to a `TEMPORARY` staging table `my_input_rows` and take it from there. Or use `VALUES` expression like in your initial code, just not directly attached to the `INSERT`, so you may need explicit type casts. See:

- [Casting NULL type when updating multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426363/casting-null-type-when-updating-multiple-rows/12427434#12427434)

I chose `min()` as it ignores `null` input. If you either have `null` or *one* distinct value per set, that does it.

This can even be done for multiple target tables in a single SQL statement, employing multiple data-modifying CTEs.