# Update one field from another table

Tags: mysql, updates

I need to update one table's fields from another table's fields. I followed exactly the same link [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763817/sql-update-fields-of-one-table-from-fields-of-another-one) but I am getting a Syntax Error.

Here is my query

```
UPDATE crm_leads
SET landlord_name = crm_owners.name,
last_name = crm_owners.last_name
FROM crm_owners
WHERE crm_owners.id =crm_leads.landlord_id
AND crm_leads.landlord_name = ''
AND crm_leads.last_name = ''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing an inner join after your UPDATE but before your SET. If I understand your schema correctly, something like this should work:

```
UPDATE crm_leads

INNER JOIN crm_owners
ON crm_owners.id = crm_leads.landlord_id

SET crm_leads.landlord_name = crm_owners.name,
crm_leads.last_name = crm_owners.last_name

WHERE crm_leads.landlord_name = ''
AND crm_leads.last_name = ''
```

Comment: Probably want to accept the answer then my friend if it worked

Answer (score 0):

Two tables:

- **`genes`**: a list of gene names (with an additional column showing the approved gene name, for direct comparison). ***We will update this table.***
- **`gene_synonyms`**: a reference / loopk-up table of approved gene names, and their synonyms (aliases). ***We will use the data in this table to update the other table.***

PSQL:

```
# SELECT * FROM genes ORDER BY id;

id  name   approved_name 
-- ------- -------------
1 AIBP    NAXE
2 ABG     A1BG
3 CHP     CHP1
4 CHP1    CHP1
5 SLCA1BP CHP1
6 NAXE    NAXE
7 AIBP    NAXE
8 APOA1BP NAXE
9 A1B     A1BG

# SELECT * FROM gene_synonyms;

id approved_name synonym 
-- ------------- -------
4 A1BG          A1B
5 A1BG          ABG
6 CHP1          CHP
7 CHP1          SLCA1BP
8 NAXE          AIBP
9 NAXE          APOA1BP
```

Update gene name in `genes` table per approved name and synonyms in `gene_synonyms` table:

```
# UPDATE genes
SET name = b.name
FROM gene_synonyms as b
WHERE NOT genes.name = b.name
AND genes.name = b.synonym;

UPDATE 7

# SELECT * from genes order by id;

id name approved_name 
-- ---- -------------
1 NAXE NAXE
2 A1BG A1BG
3 CHP1 CHP1
4 CHP1 CHP1
5 CHP1 CHP1
6 NAXE NAXE
7 NAXE NAXE
8 NAXE NAXE
9 A1BG A1BG

# SELECT * from gene_synonyms;

id approved_name synonym 
-- ------------- -------
4 A1BG          A1B
5 A1BG          ABG
6 CHP1          CHP
7 CHP1          SLCA1BP
8 NAXE          AIBP
9 NAXE          APOA1BP
```

This is based on @scott-bailey 's answer at [SO 2763817](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763817/sql-update-fields-of-one-table-from-fields-of-another-one); however, that answer is a better fit for this question (in my opinion).