# Using dynamic query + user defined datatype in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I need a function to normalize my input table `features` values.
My `features` table has 9 columns out of which `x1,x2...x6` are the input columns I need to scale.

I'm able to do it by using a static query:

```
create or replace function scale_function()
returns void as $$
declare tav1 features%rowtype; rang1 features%rowtype; 

begin   
    select avg(n),avg(x0),avg(x1),avg(x2),avg(x3),avg(x4),avg(x5),avg(x6),avg(y)
    into tav1 from features;

    select max(n)-min(n),max(x0)-min(x0),max(x1)-min(x1),max(x2)-min(x2),max(x3)-min(x3),
    max(x4)-min(x4),max(x5)-min(x5),max(x6)-min(x6),max(y)-min(y)
    into rang1 from features;

    update features
    set     x1= (x1-tav1.x1)/(rang1.x1),x2= (x2-tav1.x2)/(rang1.x2),
        x3= (x3-tav1.x3)/(rang1.x3),x4= (x4-tav1.x4)/(rang1.x4),
        x5= (x5-tav1.x5)/(rang1.x5),x6= (x6-tav1.x6)/(rang1.x6),
        y= (y-tav1.y)/(rang1.y);

return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

But now I require a dynamic query to scale *n* column values i.e., `x1,x2...,xn` (say I've 200+ columns) in my `features` table. I'm trying this code but this won't work as there is an issue with a user defined data type:

```
create or replace function scale_function(n int)
returns void as $$
declare
   tav1 features%rowtype;
   rang1 features%rowtype;
   query1 text :=''; query2 text :=''; 

begin   
for i in 0..n
    loop
        query1 := query1 ||',avg(x'||i||')';
        query2 := query2||',max(x'||i||')-min(x'||i||')';
        end loop;

    query1 := 'select avg(n)'||query1||',avg(y) into tav1 from features;';
    execute query1;

    query2 := 'select max(n)-min(n)'||query2||',max(y)-min(y) into rang1 from features;';
    execute query2;


update features
set    x1= (x1-tav1.x1)/(rang1.x1), ... ,xn=(xn-tav1.xn)/(rang1.xn)
      ,y= (y-tav1.y)/(rang1.y);

return;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Here I'm trying to take the `avg()` values of the columns into a user-defined rowtype `tav1` and have to use that `tav1` value to update.

Can any one help me how to update the `features` table values using dynamic query for 'n' such columns?

> ```
> ************ Error ************
>
> ERROR: column "avg" specified more than once
>
> SQL state: 42701
>
> Context: SQL statement "select avg(n),avg(x0),avg(x1),avg(x2),avg(x3),avg(x4),avg(x5),avg(x6),avg(y) into tav1 from features;"
>
> PL/pgSQL function scale_function(integer) line 12 at EXECUTE statement
> ```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3.0.

Comment: Please (always) provide your version of Postgres and the verbatim error message you get.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @ErwinBrandstetter, I've edited the question as per required.

Comment: The exact definition of table `features` would be helpful - what you get with `\d features` in psql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Basic `UPDATE`

Replace the first query with this much shorter and more efficient single `UPDATE` command:

```
UPDATE features
SET   (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6, y)   
    = ((x1 - g.avg1) / g.range1
     , (x2 - g.avg2) / g.range2
 --  , (x3 - ...
     , (y  - g.avgy) / g.rangey)
FROM (
   SELECT avg(x1) AS avg1, max(x1) - min(x1) AS range1
        , avg(x2) AS avg2, max(x2) - min(x2) AS range2
     -- , avg(x3) ...
        , avg(y) AS avgy, max(y) - min(y) AS rangey
   FROM   features
   ) g;
```

About the short `UPDATE` syntax:

- [SQL update fields of one table from fields of another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763817/sql-update-fields-of-one-table-from-fields-of-another-one/23283792#23283792)

#### Dynamic function

Building on the simpler query, here is a dynamic function for any number of columns:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scale_function_dyn()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   cols text;  -- list of target columns
   vals text;  -- list of values to insert
   aggs text;  -- column list for aggregate query
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO cols, vals, aggs
          string_agg(quote_ident(attname), ', ')
        , string_agg(format('(%I - g.%I) / g.%I'
                          , attname, 'avg_' || attname, 'range_' || attname), ', ')
        , string_agg(format('avg(%1$I) AS %2$I, max(%1$I) - min(%1$I) AS %3$I'
                          , attname, 'avg_' || attname, 'range_' || attname), ', ')
   FROM   pg_attribute
   WHERE  attrelid = 'features'::regclass
   AND    attname NOT IN ('n', 'x0')  -- exclude columns from update
   AND    NOT attisdropped            -- no dropped (dead) columns
   AND    attnum > 0;                 -- no system columns

   EXECUTE format('UPDATE features
                   SET   (%s) = (%s)
                   FROM  (SELECT %s FROM features) g'
                 , cols, vals, aggs);

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Related answer with more explanation:

- [Update multiple columns in a trigger function in plpgsql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343075/update-multiple-columns-in-a-trigger-function-in-plpgsql/15351196#15351196)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2c695/1)