# How do I move certain columns from one table to another in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc

So I have a table called QUEUE with the columns STUDENT_ID, S_NAME, PASSWORD
I want to write an SQL statement to copy the values within only the first 2 columns (i.e. STUDENT_ID, S_NAME) to another table STUDENT with columns STUDENT_ID, S_NAME only.

I tried this

```
insert into student (student_id, s_name) as (student_id, s_name) from queue
```

I'm new to SQL so I'm pretty sure this is incorrect. Can someone please help me out with this? Thanks. :)

Comment: Why did you tag this with every database you can think of? Which one are you actually using?

Comment: Using postgresql
sorry. fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSERT INTO .. SELECT FROM` construct like

```
insert into student (student_id, s_name) 
select student_id, s_name from queue
```

Comment: Just a note and I know but if anyone would have same problem but into db with already existing rows go here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763817/sql-update-fields-of-one-table-from-fields-of-another-one
to Scott Bailey's answer. I myself got here first and this was not solution to my problem since it created new rows under existing ones.