# Is there a repository of community made PostgreSQL functions / snippets?

Tags: postgresql

Postgres is great, but it misses many quality of life features. For example, you can't perform an UPSERT without explicitly stating all of your columns. You can code some [dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283792/1045563) to solve this, but wouldn't it be better to install someone else's code?

In almost all programming languages we have repositories of useful, community driven packages. Think pypi + pip in Python or npm in JS. Is there something similar for PostgreSQL, or at least some place to search for snippets?

I've tried to search on Google, but it is **really hard** to find anything, as most searches give you tutorials or documentation pages.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Category:Snippets

Answer (score 1):

there are , you can add custom feature using `extension` in postgresql
and there are tens of open source extensions on github apart from official extensions available for postgresql

get more information [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Extensions#Extensions)

Comment: I know that extensions exists, the problem is searching for them. Sometimes I don't need a full fledged extension, but a simple plpgsql function would do. The problem is that its too hard to search for them in google/SO.

Comment: I don't think there would be such thing , the extensions are not that huge that  something like pypi would be needed.